# Determinant of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is orthogonal. how do I show that $\det(A-2I)\not=0$.

I tried writing $A-2I=A-2AA^T=A(I-2A^T)=A(A^TA-2A^T)=AA^T(A-2I)$
but it seems that I am just doing loops after loops.

Comment: If $\det(A-2I)=0$, what can you say about the eigenvalues of A?

Comment: $\lambda=2$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: That is right, so now see if you can show that A cannot have 2 as an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

If $2$ is an eigenvalue, then $Ax = 2x$ for some $x\in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. Then, $\|x\|^2 = (x,x) = (A^TAx, x) = (Ax, Ax) = (2x,2x) = 4(x,x) = 4\|x\|^2$. Contradiction.

Comment: Also prove that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ must salsify $|\lambda| = 1$

Comment: Why $(A^TAx, x) = (Ax, Ax)$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Of course I am assuming that the setting takes place in $\Bbb R^n$. We have for any matrix$A$ and vector $x$, $(Ax,x) = (x,A^Tx)$